# libre office can't open files in other directories or partitions

Tags: partitioning, libreoffice, home-directory

LO (Kubuntu) only has access to files in the /home directory. The 'one dir up'-button stops there too and the 'path'-menu is also limited to this directory. I un- and reinstalled LO and am already out of ideas...

All other software (Okular, Gwenview...) open files in any directory or partition.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been reported on Launchpad, LibreOffice, and  Novell BugZilla.

The suggested answer is to uninstall [libreoffice-gnome](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=797855#c0). If you do not have this installed no further suggestions are made.

You can then install then install the libreoffice package. Or the standalone packages like libreoffice-writer.

It would be useful to know which version of Kubuntu, which version of LibreOffice and which package you are using.

If this does not work I suggest you add a bug report to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1085310

Comment: It's not specified as libreoffice-gnome, the version is 4.2.7.2 and I use Kubuntu 14.04